# Method execution latency while iPhone screen is off

Tags: ios, background, nsthread, latency

I have a weirdest problem and I have no idea why is this happening. I'm running a drum machine that's able to play while the app is in background.

Here's my precise timer implementation:

```
- (void)run
{
    uint64_t interval = [self computeInterval];
    mach_timebase_info_data_t info;
    mach_timebase_info(&info);

    uint64_t currentTime = mach_absolute_time();

    currentTime *= info.numer;
    currentTime /= info.denom;

    uint64_t nextTime = currentTime;

    dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();

    while (_running) {
        if (currentTime >= nextTime) {

            dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^{

                [_delegate accurateTimerDidTick:self];

            });

            interval = [self computeInterval];
            nextTime += interval;
        }

        currentTime = mach_absolute_time();
        currentTime *= info.numer;
        currentTime /= info.denom;
    }
}
```

I start it with

```
- (void)start
{
    self.running = YES;

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(run) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
```

When the app goes into background, it works perfectly, or at least the same as when the app is in the active state. It works good even when the screen is locked, but when the screen goes off, it starts to choke or slows down. So, the only difference in performance is noticeable when the screen is off or on, no matter the state of application.

Any ideas why is this happening would be appreciated!

Thank you very much in advance.

**UPDATE 1:**
Unbelievable thing: I started to check integration with Audiobus app and the first test they recommend is to run the application while Audiobus is also running to see if there's any glitches or latency in sound. Guess what - it works perfectly now! There's no difference with screen on/off anymore. I'm not sure if that's actually good or not, because now I'm confused even more. Of course, the same problem returns when the Audiobus app isn't running.

Answer (score 0):

You've effectively made an infinite loop that will eat a ton of CPU. iOS has all sorts of mechanisms to maximize battery life that are probably being activated when the screen powers off. You'll need to improve your timer so that it isn't effectively spinning at 100% CPU on 1 thread. Add some small duration sleep calls in there so the CPU can throttle down.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response! I have tried putting different sleep methods inside the while loop, but none did the trick. Maybe I'm doing something wrong or misunderstood you. Can you please push me a bit into the right direction? Which sleep method would you use, how long it should sleep? It's important to mention that I need a drum beat every 50 milliseconds max.